# Edit `\@title` in the document

Tags: titles

I am using one `info.tex` file that contains title, author names etc:

```
\author{my name}
\title{my title}
\date{\today}
```

I read this file in other files:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{info}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Now I have another file which has same author names etc., but the title is slightly different: With the previous title, I have to add "part II" (as if, `\title{my title part II}`). Instead of rewriting the title again (as I have may files like this), I want to edit the title name from this document.

I tried

```
\makeatlettezr
\let\newtitle\@title
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\newtitle}{\@title part II}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@title}{\newtitle}
\makeatother
```

but, as you expected, I got error. Can anyone help?

Comment: The problem with your code snippet is the use of `\makeatlettezr`, which doesn't exist, and the `\makeatother` ... `\makeatletter` following that. Just start out with `\makeatletter` and end with `\makeatother`. Also, use `\@title{} part II` to introduce a space after `\@title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine it using an `\edef` which expands the definition as much as possible. So you could do the following:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\@title{\@title\ part II}
\makeatother
```

If your `\title` does contain macros which shouldn't be expanded (yet) you can set things up so that `\@title` will be expanded only once with `\unexpanded\expandafter`:

```
\makeatletter
\edef\@title{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@title\ part II}}
\makeatother
```

In this case only the first token after the brace (so `\@title` in this case) will be expanded once.

Comment: This works... A small query: I want to put a new line (`\\`) before "part II". This gives error. Can you help?

Comment: @pushpen.paul did you try it with the second approach? The error is most likely because of the expansion of `\\ `. So you might want to try `\edef\@title{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@title\\ part II}}`